# Hostname variable doesn't work

Tags: debian, scripting, hostname, tftp

I'm on a Raspberry Pi using RPiTC (Raspberry Pi Thin Client).

I had made a script with an Hostname variable. It's worked perfectly but today when I had launch my script I saw something strange.

My Hostname variable doesn't work. I'm sure it's from my script, I had reload an image of my OS and it's the same. And when I take my old script (It's exactly the same script) it's worked.

So this is my script:

```
do_start()
#Creating and checking my Hostname variable
ThisHost=$(hostname)
date=$(date)
echo "This is my hostname check:"
echo $ThisHost

#This will find the file in the /home/rpitc folder and save it to a variable:
dest=$(find /home/rpitc/ -name "$ThisHost.ica")
echo "This is my dest check:"
echo $dest
findfile="${dest##*/}"
echo "This is my findfile check with extension:"
echo $findfile
echo "This is my findfile check WITHOUT extension:"
echo "${findfile%.*}"

#If check to see if my hostname $ThisHost matches the file $findfile:
if test "$ThisHost" = "${findfile%.*}"

then
echo "Worked!"
echo $ThisHost "is correct. Connected the" $date >> /home/rpitc/skelog
exit 0
else
ThisHost=$(hostname)
tftp 10.1.0.203 << fin
get /test/${ThisHost}.ica
quit
fin
if [ -s ${ThisHost}.ica ]
then
exec iceweasel /home/rpitc/${ThisHost}.ica
else
zenity --error --text="Your hostname is incorrect."
rm /home/rpitc/${ThisHost}.ica
fi
fi
```

I had transfer my script via tftp, maybe it's the problem? In the past I had transfer the same script with the tftp protocol and it's worked...

Comment: hostname variable doesn't work ? can you paste actual error ? script can be run with a +X option to give more verbosity.

Comment: My hostname variable work when I write "echo $HOSTNAME" and it's work in an other script... I don't have any error.

Comment: in your script `ThisHost=$(hostname)` which called the hostname command and store result in ThisHost as @roaima said, now you refer to `$HOSTNAME` variable, but I failled to see it in your script. My best *guess* is that you have a `hostname $foo` somewhere where foo is uninitialized.

Comment: This script worked very well yesterday. And today it's not work. Nothing change in my script. I have compare my script and my old script to see if something had change. And nothing. My old script is exactly the same and he is worked...

Answer (score 2):

You refer to a hostname variable. The construct you're using, `ThisHost=$(hostname)`, is calling the `hostname` command. Since the value is empty, it then becomes a question of why your system doesn't know its name. (You can confirm this by typing `hostname` by itself and seeing that your system has no name.)

According to [a RPi forum posting](http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=48943&p=381931) The hostname should be set from the file `/etc/hostname` at boot time from the file `/etc/init.d/hostname.sh`. So you probably want to check the contents of the file `/etc/hostname`; it should contain a single line of text that is the required hostname.

Alternatively you can set the hostname dynamically with a command such as `hostname dillon` (setting the hostname to "dillon") but this will remain effective only until the next reboot.

Comment: I have an hostname and when I use "echo $HOSTNAME" it's work.

Comment: @Aragmond, that isn't what I've suggested you try. Enter `hostname`. Not `echo $HOSTNAME`. The first command gives the machine's hostname.

Comment: My hostname command is worked too...

Comment: @Aragmond what is the output of `hostname`? And what is the output from your script for the hostname, just after `This is my hostname check:` is output?

Comment: It's okay my problem is resolved. I use ftp now and it's worked...

Answer (score 2):

There is a `"` missing at the end of line 5.

Comment: Yea I had see that after my post, It's fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was my tftp. Now I use ftp and it's worked.

When I was on tftp my file was converted in "DOS".

So now I use FTP and I convert my file in "UNIX" when I'm taking them. Thanks for your help.